# Loading an Emacs init file

Tags: emacs, filenames

In Emacs, I am putting on the menu an item to load the init.el file, since I am in there almost daily.
menu code is working fine, but the file isn't loading.
So in a buffer, for troubleshooting, I enter:

```
(load user-init-file)
```

and use `C-x C-e` to execute it.

Turns out if fails because it needs double backslashes in the path.
user-init-file resolves to `"c:\steve\emacs\init.el"`
But should be `

```
"c:\\steve\\emacs\\init.el"
```

is there a function already to convert to the double backslashes?
Or how do I do that with a search/replace?

This is similar to other search questions I found except this is for replacing within a string instead of within a buffer.

Comment: The double backslashes are not actually there in the string - that's just how they are printed. Try running `(split-string user-init-file "")` to see which characters are actually in the string.

Comment: OK, on a different computer now, but similar setup I ran:

Comment: On a computer with a little different path, I ran the following: princ(split-string user-init-file "")) and it returned in messages buffer: ( c : / e m a c s / i n i t . e l )("" "c" ":" "/" "e" "m" "a" "c" "s" "/" "i" "n" ...)
Does that help?

Comment: Are you sure you want to load it (execute the lisp code in it), or do you want to find it (open it for editing)?  It doesn't make much sense to me load it, because it's already loaded when Emacs starts.  If you're editing it and you want to reload it, you can do something like `M-x eval-buffer`.

Comment: load the init.el file is indeed what i want to do.  Am I using wrong terminology?  I cannot use M-x in this case because to be on the menu it needs to be done as  lisp command, not interactively

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably just want `(load-file user-init-file)`.  **`load-file`** does not use `load-path`, and it does not try to append `.elc` or `.el`.

(If you use MS Windows notation for a file name then you can see what Emacs really thinks the file name is, by calling `file-truename` on it.)

---

If you really want to use `load`, try `(load user-init-file nil nil t)`.

`load` tries to expand its `FILE` arg, automatically adding `.elc` and `.el`.  The 4th argument is `NOSUFFIX`, which if non-nil prevents that behavior.

`C-h f load`:

> **`load-** is a built-in function in`C source code`.
>
> `(load FILE &optional NOERROR NOMESSAGE NOSUFFIX MUST-SUFFIX)`
>
> Execute a file of Lisp code named FILE.
>
> First try `FILE` with `.elc` appended, then try with `.el`,
>   then try `FILE` unmodified (the exact suffixes in the exact order are
>   determined by `load-suffixes`).  Environment variable references in
>   `FILE` are replaced with their values by calling `substitute-in-file-name`.
>   This function searches the directories in `load-path`.
>
> If optional second arg `NOERROR` is non-`nil`,
>   report no error if `FILE` doesn't exist.
>   Print messages at start and end of loading unless
>   optional third arg `NOMESSAGE` is non-`nil` (but `force-load-messages`
>   overrides that).
>
> If optional fourth arg **`NOSUFFIX`** is non-`nil`, don't try adding
>   suffixes `.elc` or `.el` to the specified name `FILE`.
>
> If optional fifth arg `MUST-SUFFIX` is non-`nil`, insist on
>   the suffix `.elc` or `.el`; don't accept just `FILE` unless
>   it ends in one of those suffixes or includes a directory name.
>
> If **`NOSUFFIX`** is `nil`, then if a file could not be found, try looking for
>   a different representation of the file by adding non-empty suffixes to
>   its name, before trying another file.  Emacs uses this feature to find
>   compressed versions of files when Auto Compression mode is enabled.
>
> If **`NOSUFFIX`** is non-`nil`, disable this feature.
>
> The suffixes that this function tries out, when **`NOSUFFIX`** is `nil`, are
>   given by the return value of `get-load-suffixes` and the values listed
>   in `load-file-rep-suffixes`.  If `MUST-SUFFIX` is non-`nil`, only the
>   return value of `get-load-suffixes` is used, i.e. the file name is
>   required to have a non-empty suffix.
>
> When searching suffixes, this function normally stops at the first
>   one that exists.  If the option `load-prefer-newer` is non-nil,
>   however, it tries all suffixes, and uses whichever file is the newest.
>
> Loading a file records its definitions, and its `provide` and
>   `require` calls, in an element of `load-history` whose
>   car is the file name loaded.  See `load-history`.
>
> While the file is in the process of being loaded, the variable
>   `load-in-progress` is non-`nil` and the variable `load-file-name`
>   is bound to the file's name.
>
> Return `t` if the file exists and loads successfully.

Comment: load-file indeed works! it loads the init.el and executes it.  Instead, what I am trying to do is load the init.el into a buffer so I can edit it, instead of evaluating it.  I was thinking how to do that--maybe open a new buffer, switch to that buffer, then load the init.el into that buffer (so I can edit it, save it, etc) what do you think?

Comment: I don't understand. In Emacs, "loading" a Lisp (or byte-code) file means reading and *evaluating* its code. If you just want to *visit* a file then use `find-file` (or `find-file-noselect`, if you don't want to show it). I think you might like to spend a bit of time with the Emacs manual, and then maybe with the Elisp manual. Getting the jargon straight can help you find and understand additional information that you come across.

Comment: find-file-noselect will work.  I didn't even know that function existed, even after reading the emacs manual for load and load-file, and after reading the source code for them.     find-file is listed as interactive in the manual, which wouldn't work in this case.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @SteveMitchell: There is often a more general, utility function lurking in the implementation of a command, especially when there are several similar commands. Such is the case for `find-file-noselect`: it is the workhorse the visits file contents in a buffer. It doesn't do the interactive file-choosing, and it doesn't display the buffer.